# Show that $\begin{bmatrix}R&R\\0&R\end{bmatrix} \cong \begin{bmatrix}R&0\\R&R\end{bmatrix}$ for any ring $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The most natural bijection I can think of is 
$\phi(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix})= \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&c\end{bmatrix}$. I need to show this is a ring isomorphism but it is not clear to me how to show $\phi$ preserves products. Do I need a different mapping?

Comment: Have you tried applying $\phi$ to a product? What did you get?

Comment: I suspect that
$$
\phi(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix})= \begin{bmatrix}c&0\\b&a\end{bmatrix}
$$
will do what you want

Comment: Was just trying that now...thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{bmatrix}c&0\\b&a\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$

Comment: I understoodd your comment above at the same time I was trying the same thing, but can you explain this hint in particular?

Comment: With the hint, you can see that products will be preserved without writing out a matrix computation.  In particular,
$$
(PAP^{-1})(PBP^{-1}) = P(AB)P^{-1}
$$